# Why is it "die Neunziger" and not "die Neunzigen"?

Tags: declension, adjective-ending, time

When referring to the nineties (or decades in general), we say:

1. Die neunziger Jahre
2. Die Neunzigerjahre
3. Die Neunziger

My question is, where did the "er" come from?

If the "neunzig" used here is an adjective, shouldn't the declension ending be "en"?

Comment: It's a pattern for naming things. The same as it is a "Hamburger" instead of a "Hamburgen".

Comment: @äüö is it the same as "Spieler", "Kugelschreiber", "Fußgänger"...usw.?

Comment: @Hubert unfortunately it doesn't, and I actually searched here for any questions regarding "decades" before posting mine, but found nothing about where the "er" came from

Answer (score 2):

'Die Neunziger' is short (an ellipse) for 'die neunziger Jahre', dropping the 'Jahre' for brevity.

If you are talking about numbers and refer to exact instances of the number 90 in a table etc., it is 'die Neunzig' and plural 'die Neunzigen'. If you refer to numbers in the range from 90 (inclusive) to 100 (exclusive), it's 'die Neunziger' which refers to a range similar to when you say "Die neunziger (Jahre)" which is also a range of years.

As such the usual usage will always 'die Neunziger' or 'die neunziger Jahre' as 'die Neunzigen' is not sensible usage when refering to years or time in general.

Comment: What would "die neunzigen Jahre" mean in that case?

Comment: It means nothing, since "neunzig" has no conventional meaning as an adjective. Its form may look as if it were the adjectival form of a noun *Neunz, but there is no such noun either.

Comment: I have never heard *die Neunzigen*. While searching on Google, the very few hits I got were OCR errors.

Comment: The second paragraph confused me for a while before I understood that you meant to speak of several instances of numbers "90". This just seems *very* rare (not to say artificial) for numbers except perhaps digits as in "Die Zahl 199000 ist eine Eins gefolgt von zwei Neun**en** und dann drei Null**en**"

Comment: @planetmaker It is never "die Neunzigen" if you refer to numbers in a table it would still be "die Neunziger" you might be mistaking it with "den Neunzigern"

Comment: @Trae No, I don't. If I refer to the numbers in a table and mean the exact numbers: "Die Neunzigen in Spalten A und B müssten sicher auch mindestens Sechsundneunzigen sein, damit das mit der Fehlerabschätzung passt". Eine Neunzig. Mehrere Neunzigen im Sinne von Zahlen (wie Hagen von Eitzen auch erklärt). Persönlich empfinde ich es als nicht ungewöhnlich - kommt aber sicher darauf an, ob man tagtäglich mit Zahlen umgeht oder nicht.

Comment: Im Gegensatz zu "Eine Neunzig, mehrere Neunzigen" bedeutet für mich die Nutzung von "die Neunziger in Spalten A und B", dass alle Zahlen von 90...99,999... gemeint sind. Insofern ist es für mich ein semantischer Unterschied, welchen Begriff ich verwende.

Comment: @planetmaker Konnte es bis vor kurzem nirgends finden (und kenne es sprachgebruachlich einfach gar nicht) aber laut https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Neunzig hast du Recht "Plural: die Neunzigen", mein Fehler!